# Rails 5 accessing context for non-nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with a ContentCategory model that

```
has_many :contents
```

In the `ContentCategoriesController#show` view there is a button for `New Content`.

This goes to the `ContentsController#new` view which has a select box for the content_category.

Currently, this defaults to the first category in the list instead of the desired behavior of defaulting to the ContentCategory of the page before.
Is there a way to achieve this without nesting the resources in `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by passing parameter to ContentsController's new method from ContentCategory's show page like

```
new_content_path(content_category_id: @content_category.id)
```

Than use it to auto select Content Category in select box on new page.

Comment: This works with the `link_to` helper but I am using `button_to` so I used the following syntax: `= button_to "New Content", new_content_path, :method => :get, params: { content_category_id: @content_category.id }`. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!